# How do I access an array inside a json object?

Tags: json, vue.js, rest, axios

I am using axios to access the OMDB api. The returned value is saved to a ref([]) object called ombdRatings in my vue component, and I'm trying to access these values to be displayed in the DOM. Here's the returned json:

```
{"Title":"Parasite","Year":"1982","Rated":"R","Released":"12 Mar 1982","Runtime":"85 min","Genre":"Horror, Sci-Fi","Director":"Charles Band","Writer":"Alan J. Adler, Michael Shoob, Frank Levering","Actors":"Robert Glaudini, Demi Moore, Luca Bercovici","Plot":"In a post-apocalyptic USA, a doctor/scientist infected with a new strain of parasite ends up in a small desert town, trying to find a cure.","Language":"English","Country":"United States","Awards":"N/A","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTFlZDVjMDMtODkwNS00MTM3LWJiMzQtY2IxN2JiNWZjMWUxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"4.0/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"17%"}],"Metascore":"N/A","imdbRating":"4.0","imdbVotes":"2,574","imdbID":"tt0084472","Type":"movie","DVD":"30 Oct 2017","BoxOffice":"N/A","Production":"Embassy Pictures","Website":"N/A","Response":"True"}
```

The ratings are stored in an array in my object. When I try to access the first item on the array to display in the DOM like: `{{ omdbRatings.Ratings[0] }}` then I get an error like

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading '1')

I can access other items in the object, but I don't know how I can access this array in my DOM with interpolation.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. There is no access to `1` (most likely the second element in the array) in the code you posted. "ref([]) object" - it's an *array*, not just object. If you assign a plain object to this ref, this is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when axios is not done ,ratings and Value are undefined，so it is wrong. you can need to ratings is exist。you wirte code:

```
<div v-if="omdbRatings&&omdbRatings.Ratings&&......">.....</div>
```

This is tedious.

Simple，code is right.
in js，you can：

```
console.log(omdbRatings?.Ratings?.[0]?.Value||'--');
```

but template，you need template supposed Optional_chaining：

```
export const optionalChaining = (obj, ...rest) => {
  let tmp = obj;
  for (let key in rest) {
    let name = rest[key];
    tmp = tmp?.[name];
  }
  return tmp || "";
}
```

so，template use:

```
{{optionalChaining(omdbRatings,"Ratings",'0','Value')||'--'}}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).